# compare contents of two files in bash

Tags: bash, grep, comparison

I have two files tmp1.txt and tmp2.txt

tmp1.txt has

```
aaa.txt
bbb.txt
ccc.txt
ddd.txt
eee.txt
aab.txt
```

tmp2.txt has

```
aaa.txt
aac.txt
bbb.txt
bbd.txt
ccc.txt
ddd.txt
zzz.txt
yyy.txt
```

I want to compare these two files and give me these results in bash

1. files that are in both tmp1.txt and tmp2.txt which would be aaa.txt, bbb.txt, ccc.txt, ddd.txt
2. files that are in tmp1.txt but not in tmp2.txt which would be eee.txt, aab.txt
3. files that are in tmp2.txt but not in tmp1.txt which would be aac.txt, bbd.txt, zzz.txt, yyy.txt

Comment: Nothing built-in is going to give you that exact output but `comm` will get you the details you want. If you want that format you'll have to post process it though.

Comment: ...and `comm` will behave far faster and more memory-efficiently. Now -- you showed all the values in sort order here; was that for-example-only, or is that a genuine guarantee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can roll your own solution using `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { a[$0]++; next }
{
    print ($0 in a ? "In both: " $0: "In tmp2.txt: " $0); 
    delete a[$0]
}
END {
    for(left in a) print "In tmp1.txt: " left
}
' tmp1.txt tmp2.txt 
In both: aaa.txt
In tmp2.txt: aac.txt
In both: bbb.txt
In tmp2.txt: bbd.txt
In both: ccc.txt
In both: ddd.txt
In tmp2.txt: zzz.txt
In tmp2.txt: yyy.txt
In tmp1.txt: eee.txt
In tmp1.txt: aab.txt
```

and may be pipe it to `sort -k2`:

```
awk '...' | sort -k2
In both: aaa.txt
In both: bbb.txt
In both: ccc.txt
In both: ddd.txt
In tmp1.txt: aab.txt
In tmp1.txt: eee.txt
In tmp2.txt: aac.txt
In tmp2.txt: bbd.txt
In tmp2.txt: yyy.txt
In tmp2.txt: zzz.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters mentioned, the `comm` command will do what you're looking for, with a caveat: The files have to be sorted first. Fortunately that's easy.

```
$ sort tmp1.txt > tmp1_sorted.txt
$ sort tmp2.txt > tmp2_sorted.txt
```

Then:

```
$ comm tmp1_sorted.txt tmp2_sorted.txt
                aaa.txt
aab.txt
        aac.txt
                bbb.txt
        bbd.txt
                ccc.txt
                ddd.txt
eee.txt
        yyy.txt
        zzz.txt
```

Per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm), "With no options, [comm] produce three-column output. Column one contains lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to FILE2, and column three contains lines common to both files."

If you want to get the columns individually, you can pass the options `-1`, `-2`, or `-3` to suppress the first, second, or third column respectively, so to get just the first column, for example, you would do:

```
$ comm -23 tmp1_sorted.txt tmp2_sorted.txt
aab.txt
eee.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

`#!/bin/bash`
`old=file1`
`new=file2`
`cmp --silent $old $new  && echo " Files are identicals " || echo "Files are different"`